# Server IP variable in received_header_text in exim config

Tags: configuration, exim

I would like to change received_header_text in exim config and I need to use server IP in it.

Is there a variable that I can use there to get server IP?

---

What I try to do:

[See related question.](https://serverfault.com/questions/669584/failed-spf-for-email-imported-to-gmail-because-of-client-ip-instead-of-servers/670427?noredirect=1#comment821971_670427)

I thought about changing:

```
received_header_text = Received: ${if def:sender_rcvhost {from $sender_rcvhost\n\t}{${if def:sender_ident {from ${quote_local_part:$sender_ident} }}${if def:sender_helo_name {(helo=$sender_helo_name)\n\t}}}}by $primary_hostname ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}(Exim $version_number)\n\t${if def:sender_address {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}id $message_exim_id${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}
```

to:

```
received_header_text = ${if def:authenticated_id {Received: from $primary_hostname ([188.40.153.39] helo=[188.40.153.39]) by $primary_hostname with ESMTP\n\t(Exim $version_number)\n\t${if def:sender_address {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}id $message_exim_id${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}\n\t}}Received: ${if def:sender_rcvhost {from $sender_rcvhost\n\t}{${if def:sender_ident {from ${quote_local_part:$sender_ident} }}${if def:sender_helo_name {(helo=$sender_helo_name)\n\t}}}}by $primary_hostname ${if def:received_protocol {with $received_protocol}} ${if def:tls_cipher {($tls_cipher)\n\t}}(Exim $version_number)\n\t${if def:sender_address {(envelope-from <$sender_address>)\n\t}}id $message_exim_id${if def:received_for {\n\tfor $received_for}}
```

Comment: Have you tried it? What's your expected output and what's the actual output? See [How can I ask better questions on Server Fault?](http://meta.serverfault.com/questions/3608/how-can-i-ask-better-questions-on-server-fault)

Comment: Duplicate of (the slightly better question) http://serverfault.com/questions/671882/cant-find-received-header-text-in-exim-config-file . Answered there.

Comment: It's a separate question because here I ask about IP - how could I put server IP into received_header_text without hard coding it but using some variable. So it won't need to be changed when IP of the server changes.